# Software updater freezes during update

Tags: 19.10, update-manager

My software Updater on **ubuntu 19.10** freezes after reaching a certain point while installing updates. It has this update that's been asking permission for months now and every time I start it, it downloads the updates but fails to install them because it freezes while writing **applying changes**..

Does anyone know if there is a bug somewhere? I tried searching the internet but to no avail..
I've attached a screenshot of some of the packages to be updated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I would perform upgrades via terminal (so messages appear on the display allowing you to detect & fix issues, which I find easier than looking in logs).  Many of your packages look like 3rd party too,  Don't forget your 19.10 release reaches EOL today, so *release-upgrade* asap to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2020-July/005494.html

Comment: I actually didn't know that my 19.10 will be terminated today ! I didn't get any alerts ..But I will do as you suggested thanks !

Comment: fyi: 19.10 means the 2019-October release, a standard release has 9 months from release date which means this month... Without looking up the actual date, release date is usually 3rd Thursday of release month, which gives a good clue without looking up any date/release-notes/eol-warning-notices.

Comment: fyi:  you should have received an alert suggested you upgrade to 20.04, however this can be dismissed in a *don't alert me again* fashion which stops further alerts.  the upgrade prompt is the major alert that EOL is approaching (for non-LTS releases).

Comment: Thank you for telling me that.. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and I have a lot to learn about it and I can use all the help that I can get! Ok so now it says that to upgrade I need to fully update the system first and that is not working.. I'll try again updating using apt ..

Comment: That is expected (yes you should full-upgrade before you *release-upgrade*), and the messages are clues as to your problem..  Once your machine has fully-upgraded (issues resolved), then I'd reboot before starting the `do-release-upgrade` steps (follow the next release's *release notes* (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes) on the *release-upgrade* process)

Comment: Well I launched the full-upgrade and it's working now unpacking packages and all ..I hope it'll work this time...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using apt in a terminal?

Open terminal and type the following (enter your password when prompted for it)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If any error messages are shown, please post them here

But, really consider upgrading to 20.04, because the 19.10 support has officially ended, so the repositories are no longer maintained.

Comment: Yes actually I did try using apt in terminal and I searched the errors on the internet but nothing solved the issue.. But I will be upgrading to 20.04 now ..I actually didn't know that the support for the 19.10 ended.. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted. On my broken Ubuntu 20.04 system, I also had to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, [as I explain in my new answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1444179/327339).

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to do:

```bash
sudo apt update

sudo apt full-upgrade
# ...which told me to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, so I did that:
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Then, re-run the Software Updater GUI tool.

### See also:

1. [Where I learned about `sudo apt full-upgrade` from @Ferdi](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259782/327339)
2. My answer which I updated with info. from this answer: [Super User: `sudo apt-get update` couldn't create temporary file](https://superuser.com/a/1756343/425838)